# Custom form cant save email value to list from dropdown input

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powerapp, powerapps-forms, office-365-groups

Have big problem, i created custom form and one input is Person type in dropdown input. This input i limited only for persons in specific group.

Problem is, if i choose one member from the group, save button did not save person email to the list.

All other inputs in custom form, are saved.

`Dropdown advance setup`

```
OnSelect - false
OnChange - false
DisplayFields - ["mail"]
SearchFields -  ["mail"]
Items - Office365Groups.ListGroupMembers("id").value
IsSearchable - true
```

`SharePointForm setup`

```
If(
   IsBlank(SharePointIntegration.Selected) || IsEmpty(SharePointIntegration.Selected),
   First([@tab]),
   SharePointIntegration.Selected
  )
```

`Save` and `edit` buttons are not custom, using default one.

thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `items` property of dropdown/combobox to:

```
ForAll(
    Filter(
        Office365Groups.ListGroupMembers("id").value, 
        "@company.com" in Mail
    ),
    { 
       Claims:"i:0#.f|membership|" & Lower(Mail), 
       Department: "", 
       DisplayName: DisplayName, 
       Email: Mail, 
       JobTitle: "", 
       Picture: ""
    }
)
```

Replace `@company.com` with your company/tenant name as per email address.

Then set `Update` property of your Data card control to:

```
ComboboxControlName.SelectedItems
```

**Reference**: [PowerApps People picker column issues](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/PowerApps-People-picker-column-issues/td-p/1199602)